# Set alarm for 1 min but it called after 5 minutes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I have set alarm for 1 minutes but it called after every 5 minutes.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.example"); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //pending intent
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, new Date().getTime(), 60000, pendingIntent);  //time duration is 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

USE alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, new Date().getTime(), 60000, pendingIntent);  //time duration is 60 seconds Instead of
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, new Date().getTime(), 60000, pendingIntent);  //time duration is 60 seconds

Comment: what is the difference between both method? can you expalin.

Comment: setInexactRepeating more power-efficient than the strict recurrences traditionally supplied by setRepeating

Comment: But setInexactRepeating not alarm exactly

Comment: i have checked it later it called after 5 minutes in sumsung devices. In my lenovo device works fine call alarm after every 1 minutes.