# Executing RxAndroid Observables after my application is closed

Tags: android, rx-java, background-process, rx-android

Is it possible to keep my Observable running after an Android application is closed?

In my example, I have to send the user's location with an interval of 10 seconds. I initially supposed that subscribing on `Schedulers.newThread()` would do the trick , however , whenever I close the app the process stops. Is there any way I can do this with RxAndroid?

Here is the method that I Use:

```
private void startShiftLocationUpdater() {

    Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(l -> shouldSendLocation())
            .takeWhile(shouldSend -> shouldSend)
            .flatMap(shouldSend -> initUpdateLocationShift())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(s -> {
                repository.updateShift(s);
                Log.i("ShiftUpdate", "Shift updated successfully");
            }, Crashlytics::logException, () ->
                Log.i("ShiftUpdate", "Shift updated completed")
            );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close the app"? Do you kill process? Force close or remove from recents view?

Comment: Moreover, you have much bigger problems: Doze mode in Android 6.0+, background location restrictions on Android 8.0+, and the irritation of users for draining their battery so fast.

Comment: @elmorabea , I force close the app

Comment: Aren't the Schedulers supposed to be daemon threads as default in RxAndroid? Therefore , continue executing even though the app is killed?

Comment: That depends entirely on your definition of "app is killed". If you mean "process is terminated", then threads go away when the process does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to continue executing code in background and [wakelocks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) but I had to do something similar at what you describe and found out that services can be killed at any moment if the android system requires free memory.

The solution I found was to use [alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), if you schedule alarms this alarms will be fired whether your app is still executing or not. That way my app could get the device position even though the system had killed the app due to lack of resources. It's the only solution I found that works in this scenario.

The idea came to me in some google i/o when they said that if you really need your app to continue no matter what you should use alarms instead of services.

The only problem I had was that, on some specific Huawei devices, the alarms that had to be executed before 5 minutes from the time they were created just fired after 5 minutes and not at the time you set. So, I finally made a solution involving a service and alarms. This way when an alarm arrived if the service was running the service was stopped and restarted and a position was retrieved. And in that specific Huawei devices the service was always executing sending positions but if, for some reason, the app was killed the alarm would restore everything in less than 5 minutes.

At that moment I didn't use Rx, it was time ago, and using alarms was the solution for not to losing any track of the route. Our app was widely used, I don't say the name only because I don't want to spam here.

I hope I'll explained this alarm issue well. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try before accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: If you force close the the application, and the services are running in the same process, the service will be killed as well

Comment: @elmorabea Yes, that's why I used alarms in the end. Actually I used a solution involving services and alarms due to some Huawei restrictions with the alarms. I'll update the answer with all the info about this in a moment.

Comment: adding a link for further reading about alarms in Android 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Maybe the 5 minutes issue was happening because I used inexact repeating alarms and wasn't related to a vendor issue as I concluded at that moment. I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865893/set-alarm-for-1-min-but-it-called-after-5-minutes